# Azure App Service: Can't publish existing app service to Linux

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

I've created an Azure Linux app service with an ARM deployment, and I want to publish my .NET Core Web API project to the app service. The publish wizard doesn't allow me to publish to an existing Linux app service (though it permits Windows app services). If I download the Publish Profile, that allows me to set up a connection, but the "Validate Connection" button gives an invalid connection. The error message is as follows:

[image]

How can I publish to this service?

Comment: If my reply is helpful, you could mark it as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM=false` in the app settings for your site, and re-download the publish profile (e.g. from VS).

If it is invalid, I recommend you to [contact Azure support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) for help, [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/efa56eb2-a8b2-4690-92d0-33d97946ed29/cant-deploy-could-not-connect-to-the-remote-computer-quotxxxscmazurewebsitesnetquot-using?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) is a similar issue, you could refer to it.

> This is not normal, and we need to investigate deeper. As a test, if you create a brand new test site (same region), do you also see this? If so, can you share the name of your test site to help investigation, and the approx time when you tried (preferably UTC)?